# pentaho: "get rows from result" --> Fields 'xyz' used in the condition are not found in input from previous steps

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Anyone who could show me an example for a "copy rows to result"/"get rows from result"-Job?
I am talking about a successfully tested job.

Goal:

1. "Get rows from result" is sending some keywords.
2. "Get file names" delivers all the files a certain directory is containing.
3. Filter rows" looks for certain files, i.e. it is using the keywords to find the files (transf. will run in a loop, i.e. "Execute every input row" is checked).

Comment: What have you tried on your own

Answer (score 0):

Have got:

1. One Job
2. Within this job I've got two transformations
3. Transf. 1 reads a text file and copies the result. It does work properly since the "preview data" shows the values I want to pass.
4. "Execute every input row" is checked in the settings of the 2nd transf. as well as the "copy result to parameters".
5. Transf. 2 begins with a "Get rows from result", the preview does not show any values. "Input fields" can't find any field.
6. "Stream column name" is the same as the column name of the column copied to the result

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
2nd transformation should contain only the following steps:

1. "Get file names": Use the parameter to find the certain file(s=can be multiple, hence  "execute every input row" is still checked). In my case, I've used it within the "Wildcard"-column
2. "Set files in result"